# how do we show $\wedge^2 I \neq 0$ but $\wedge^2 A=0$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, exterior-algebra

The following question is from **Appendix C** of Matsumura's Commutative ring Theory, page $283$.

Given an Ideal $I \subset A$ of a ring $A$, the author claims that it might happens that the exterior product $\wedge^2 A=0$, but still $\wedge^2 I \neq 0$. The author given the following example:

Let $k$ be a field and $A=k[x,y]$ be the polynomial ring and $I=xA+yA$ be the ideal. Then he claimed that $\wedge^2 I \neq 0$ by defining a map $\varphi: I \times I \to k=A/I$ by $$\varphi(f,g)=[\partial (f,g)/\partial (x,y)]_{(x,y)=(0,0)}$$  with $\varphi(x,y)=1$ so that $\varphi \neq 0$ and so $\wedge^2I \neq 0$.

But I didn't understand at some places as follows:

At first $\varphi (f,g)$ is the jacobian matrix and so $\varphi(x,y)=$identiry matrix. But it is given $1$.

Also how do we show $\wedge^2 I \neq 0$ but $\wedge^2 A=0$ ?

Any explanation please

Comment: I think it's supposed to be the jacobian determinant.

Comment: @CaptainLama, thanks. How to argue that the exterior product $\wedge^2I \neq 0$ and $\wedge^2 A=0$ ?

Comment: @Mathlearner $\varphi$ is bilinear and antisymetric so it induces a map $\bigwedge^2 I\to k$. Since $\varphi\neq 0$, $\bigwedge^2 I$ is also non zero. However $\bigwedge^2A=0$ (this is a general fact, for any free module $A^n$, $\bigwedge^k A^n=0$ if $k>n$)

Comment: @Roland, thanks. I think in the second case, if we consider any alternating tensor $f \wedge g \in \wedge^2 A$, then $f \wedge g=fg(1 \wedge 1)=0$, but can we pull out $f$ and $g$ ? If so, then any element in $\wedge^2 A$ can be made $0$

Comment: Yes we can pull out $f$ and $g$ and this is why $\bigwedge^2A=0$.

Comment: @Roland, thanks a lot. But this same technique does not work in case of $\wedge^2 I$, is not very clear to me.  Is it because of lack of linear independence in $\wedge^2 I$ ?

Comment: If $f,g$ are in $I$, then $f\wedge g\in\bigwedge^2 I$. But you can't write $f\wedge g=fg(1\wedge 1)$ because $1\not\in I$ and so $1\wedge 1\not\in\bigwedge^2 I$

Comment: @Roland, ahh.  It was simple. Thanks